# What is the progmem equivalen for ARM Cortex M0?

Tags: c, arm

I want to store my data array in flash, so I am doing `const table[TABLE_SIZE] = {};`. When working with AVR, I remember I used the `PROGMEM` attribute. Does using `const` do the same as `PROGMEM` or is there a way to use `PROGMEM` in my M0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `static const`. That's not precisely what it means, but most embedded compilers will interpret that as a sign that they should leave the table in ROM (and not add a copy to RAM). Note that you'll need to actually initialize it in the static initializer: you can't use `{}` and initialize it at runtime.

Comment: `static` will make is accessible only from the same compile unit. It's not necessary for placing the variable in the flash; just `const` is enough.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: The problem might be on some that embedded platforms, you may not be able to get a regular pointer to data in flash. This problem is avoided when an array is `static const`, and the compiler can use non-standard pointers everywhere within that single TU.

Comment: The question specifies Cortex-M0 so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky That's true: `const` alone often is enough. I should have asked for more context from the OP about the scope of the variable and what exactly he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you guys. Even though I am using `{}` and initialize at runtime, the `RO-` and `RW-data` shows that it stores to flash (read only expands).